# Is midipolyaftertouch broken in csound?

Tags: midi, csound, cabbage

I'm not having much luck with the midipolyaftertouch opcode. Basically

```
kPea init 0.1
midipolyaftertouch kPea, 1, 0.1, 0.9
printk2 kPea
```

does not actually respond to polyphonic aftertouch messages. On the other hand, a manually coded rough equivalent

```
kPea init 0.1
kstatus,kchan,kdata1,kdata2 midiin
if (kstatus==160 && kchan==1) then
    kPea = kdata2 * 0.007
    printk2 kPea
endif
```

works fine. So is this a known bug in `midipolyaftertouch` ? I can't find any usage examples for `midipolyaftertouch`, besides those from the manual, so I'm guess hardly anyone used it... By the way `aftouch` gets the channel not the per-note after-touch (pressure), i.e. `aftouch` queries kstatus == 208 (and actually does work, but of course it's not per note). For the difference see [this](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/24088/how-does-the-midi-data-for-polyphonic-aftertouch-differ-from-normal-aftertouch).

I'm using Csound version 6.13 beta from inside Cabbage 2.3.0 on Windows (because that's what ships with that version of Cabbage).

Answer (score 0):

There's another opcode namely `polyaft` that actually works, following the documentation

```
kPea init 0.1
inote   notnum          ; note number
kPea    polyaft inote, 0.1, 0.9
printk2 kPea
```

Looking at the C source for `midipolyaftertouch` it is actually indexed exactly the same way as for `polyaft`. So based on that I tried:

```
kPea init 0.1
inote   notnum          ; note number
midipolyaftertouch kPea, inote, 0.1, 0.9
printk2 kPea
```

and this actually works too.

In the MIDI API jargon, "MIDI controller [number]" (usually) [means](https://www.mathworks.com/help/audio/ug/midi-control-surface-interface.html) key/note [number]... unlike in world of DAWs where [one](https://www.cakewalk.com/Support/Knowledge-Base/2007012925/Using-multiple-MIDI-controllers-in-SONAR-3) uses e.g. "multiple MIDI controllers" to mean several keyboards, not several keys of the same keyboard... Also, Csound has a notion of multiple controllers in the latter/DAW sense, selected by the -M startup switch, although it [calls](http://www.csounds.com/manual/html/CommandFlags.html) them "MIDI devices".

The code example for `midipolyaftertouch` from the documentation can't possibly work unless you just try it with D0 as the key/note; insert joke about the broken clock here. Interestingly the documentation was written by the source code author for that opcode, so it wasn't a case of someone else misunderstanding the code...